# How to get innerHTML attribute value "r" in this code?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using D3.js for my personal project.

But, I faced with some troubles.

[image]

```
        bubble.nodes(root)
        svg = d3.select("svg").attr("class", "bubble")

        var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
            .data(bubble.nodes(root)
                .filter(function(d) {
                    return !d.children;
                }))
            .enter()
            .append("g")
            .attr("class", "node")
            .attr("transform", function(d) {
                return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
            })
```

In the picture, I want to get "r" value in the circle.
How can I get this value?
Also, this circle is one part of bubble chart node.

Comment: I haven't used D3, but can you access that `<circle>` element directly from the object you logged? You could just read the `r` attribute from it.

Answer (score 0):

Using vanilla JS...  `getElementsByTagName('circle')`, then `getAttribute('r')` to find the value of `r`

```js
let circle = document.getElementsByTagName('circle');
let target = circle[0].getAttribute('r');
console.log(target);
```

```html
<circle r="0.75847397430597"></circle>
```